# Memory Management - CVPixelBuffer to UIImage, difference between using CIImage and VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, cvpixelbuffer

I got two solution converting `CVPixelBuffer` to `UIImage`.

1. Using CIImage and its context

First solution is using `CIImage` and `CIContext`.

```
func readAssetAndCache(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    /** Setup AVAssetReader **/
    reader.startReading()

    let context = CIContext()
    while let sampleBuffer = generator.trackoutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
        autoreleasepool {
            guard let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

            let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
            guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return }

            if let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage) {
                CacheManager.default.cache(image: image, forKey: "CachedImages") {
                   completion()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer

Code Looks like this.

```
func readAssetAndCache(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        /** Setup AVAssetReader **/

    reader.startReading()

    while let sampleBuffer = generator.trackoutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
        autoreleasepool {
            guard let imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

            if let image = UIImage(pixelBuffer: imageBuffer,
                                   scale: 1.0,
                                   orientation: self.imageOrientation) {
                CacheManager.default.cache(image: image, forKey: "CachedImages") {

                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this solution I use this extension method.

```
import UIKit
import VideoToolbox

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, scale: CGFloat, orientation: UIImageOrientation) {
            var image: CGImage?
            VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, nil, &image)

            guard let cgImage = image else { return nil }

            self.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: orientation)
        }
    }
```

Whole process related to extracting images from video is as follows.

#### Whole Process

1. Extract All frames serially.
2. Cache each image in disk concurrently, using `OperationQueue`.

#### Question

The problem occurs when images are cached concurrently, using `CIContext` and its `createCGImage(ciImage:rect:)`. Memory footprints gets higher until the end of all caching process in first scenario. But, Second way, it releases its memory when each workItem is finished.

I really don't know why.

Here is my Caching method related to this problem.

```
func cache(image: UIImage, forKey key: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let operation = BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.diskCache(image: image)
    })
    operation.completionBlock = completion
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}

func diskCache(image: UIImage) {
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

    let key = "\(self.identifierPrefix).jpg"

    FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: self.cachePath.appendingPathComponent(key).path,
                                   contents: data, attributes: nil)
}
```